# Share answer/comment URL is genius. How does it work?

Tags: discussion, comments, sharing

TIL that when using the share link on a stackexchange comment you get a URL that looks like this:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/51139

However, it has no hashtag like the destination page does after it loads.

More over, that ID is the hash of the comment I wanted to share, and there is no reference in that shareable URL of the question ID, which is a different number (51137).

When clicked, some kind of magic happens and I'm assuming there is a lookup as to what question ID that comment ID belongs to, and then it redirects with the original comment parameter added as a fragment.

I'm interested in learning how that works as I see it as a clever way to share leaner, shorter links (especially ones with # ids). How exactly does that work?

Comment: Instead of "comment", do you mean "answer"? Because that's what the link points at.

Comment: *“I'm interested in learning how that works as I see it as a clever way to share leaner, shorter links”* — This isn't something about how links with IDs works in general, mind, it's something particular that the site software here does on purpose. It won't work elsewhere on the Internet, if that's what you're hoping.

Comment: Oh no - just curious on the architecture of it. I am thinking of emulating it on my own CMS in the future.

Comment: @atwixtor wait for the official answer from SE team. Like I said in my answer you can customized 301 redirect in your programming language / script.

Answer (score 11):

All posts on a Stack Exchange site - both questions and answers - have an ID. This ID is wrapped into the share link. In the case of your link, the answer ID is 51139. The server knows that this ID, 51139, belongs to question 51137, so it can redirect you there with a hash appended to the question URL.

So, summarized, the redirection works like this:

```
(questions)
http://site.stackexchange.com/q/1234
-->
http://site.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/title
```

and:

```
(answers)
http://site.stackexchange.com/a/1234
-->
http://site.stackexchange.com/questions/<corresponding question ID>/title/1234#1234
```

The server is also clever enough to redirect you correctly even if you specified an incorrect type in the share link, for example https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/51139 has a `/q/`, but it would still redirect you to the answer.

How does it scroll to the correct answer? It works like this: on top of each answer, there is an `a` tag with the `name` attribute set to the answer ID:

```
<a name="51139"></a>
```

When a URL ends with `#something`, then your browser will automatically scroll to the element with `name` or `id` "something". That's what happens here.

Comment: Are these redirects features of the CMS this platform uses, or are they custom scripts?

Comment: @atwixtor I don't know to be honest; I'm not a Stack Exchange dev.

Comment: +1 for the simplified answer but as for the "server knows that this ID" goes, its technically using 301 Redirect URL. See my answer for details.

Comment: @HackerKarma Nice find! +1

Comment: @ProgramFOX We will have to wait for SE's official answer on how they have implemented 301 redirect in their server side script.

Comment: @HackerKarma I suppose that's just some database queries and HTTP responses...

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in knowing what kind of regex they use in any 301 redirects, and how much the database provides (lookup of question by comment ID). Thanks for the info, people!

Comment: @ProgramFOX only SE's team can tell for sure. Apart from customized script, it could be a server side configuration (see my edited answer)

Comment: @atwixtor I'm pretty sure they are using the power of MVC for this: http://www.dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/understanding-url-rewriting-and-url-attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-mvc5-with-examples

Comment: @atwixtor Our software is not built on any CMS (it's an ASP.NET MVC application), so "features of the CMS this platform uses" makes no sense. Also, we don't use any regexes for this.

Comment: @ProgramFOX As mentioned in my answer, both `/q/` and `/a/` go to the same controller action, so our system does exactly the same thing for the two. The `PostTypeId` of the associated post is what determines whether something is a question or answer (or neither, in which case we return a 404).

Answer (score 9):

`/q/$postid[/$userid]` and `/a/$postid[/$userid]` are actual routes in our system, with an actual controller action attached (both of those routes go to the same action—questions and answers both live in the `Posts` table, just with different `PostTypeId`s).

Depending on whether the post is a question or an answer, the appropriate type of link is generated as the redirection target. Getting the associated question ID and slug requires hitting the database (or cache), so no, these aren't just simply rewrite configuration rules. :-)

Answer (score 4):

> When clicked, some kind of magic happens and I'm assuming there is a
>   lookup as to what question ID that comment ID belongs to, and then it
>   redirects with the original comment parameter added as a fragment.

Yes, the **magic happens** at the **server side**. It's done by customizing **Redirect - 301 Moved Permanently**.

Here is the result summary of [**Redirect Check**](http://redirectcheck.com/):

> Input URL: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/51139
>
> Destination URL:
>   `https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51137/converting-cmyk-pdf-to-rgb/51139#51139`
>
> Number of redirects: 1
>
> Status code: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

Here is the result screenshot of [**Redirect Check**](http://redirectcheck.com/):

**Click on the image to enlarge it.**

[image]

As for OP's comment goes,

> Oh no - just curious on the architecture of it. I am thinking of
>   emulating it on my own CMS in the future

Since SE's platform is a closed-source we won't know how exactly its done on the server side. But, there are lots of good sources on the internet and in our very own Stack Overflow (search for '301 url redirect' and use language tag to filter).

You can implement 301 redirect ([recommended for SEO](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)) in various [programming language](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php) (tweak sample examples as per custom requirement) and server side configuration. Another excellent resource is [Wikipedia's URL redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) which has many examples of 301 Redirect including '[nginx rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) with http_map_module' (SE uses 'Cloudflare nginx' server) and '[Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)' module (especially 'RewriteMap' directive).

Also, MVC frameworks like ASP.NET MVC, Ruby on Rails, etc. offer powerful features in *customizing routes* for handling, routing, and responding to HTTP requests within an application.